# Problema con libreria en Eclipse

Tags: java

```
import org.pircbotx.Configuration;
import org.pircbotx.PircBotX;
import org.pircbotx.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import org.pircbotx.hooks.types.GenericMessageEvent;

public class MyListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGenericMessage(GenericMessageEvent event) {
            //When someone says ?helloworld respond with "Hello World"
            if (event.getMessage().startsWith("?helloworld"))
                    event.respond("Hello world!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            //Configure what we want our bot to do
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
                            .setName("PircBotXUser") //Set the nick of the bot. CHANGE IN YOUR CODE
                            .addServer("irc.freenode.net") //Join the freenode network
                            .addAutoJoinChannel("#pircbotx") //Join the official #pircbotx channel
                            .addListener(new MyListener()) //Add our listener that will be called on Events
                            .buildConfiguration();

            //Create our bot with the configuration
            PircBotX bot = new PircBotX(configuration);
            //Connect to the server
            bot.startBot();
    }
}
```

He descargado la libreria PircBotX ,tengo un serio problema y es que al ejercutar el codigo de arriba me salta el siguiente error en consola.`Error: Could not find or load main class MyListener
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pircbotx/hooks/ListenerAdapter`
 tengo entendido que es algo relacionado con el classpatch pero no estoy muy seguro.

Comment: ¿has probado a ir al Build Path de tu proyecto e importar la librería a la que te refieres?

Comment: Si pero sigue fallando por alguna razon